# Beginner python difficulties with for loop+recursive loop

Tags: python

I am receiving:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

on the for loop in the first definition.

I have no idea what is going on or what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
initialbudget=3329
annualInterestRate=0.2
flat= 50
def formula(flat):
    '''
    input flat rate
    return low or correct
    '''
    balance=initialbudget
    for i in range(1, 13):
        balance=(balance-flat)*(1+annualInterestRate/12.0)
    if balance==0:
        return ('correct')
    elif balance>0:
        return ('low')



def rateFinder(initialbudget):
    '''
    input starting balance
    return Flat rate needed to pay off balance in 12 months
    '''
    flat=0 
    while formula(flat) != ('high'):
        if formula(flat)==('correct'):
            return('Lowest Payment:'+ ' ' + str(flat))
        else:
            flat+=10
            return(rateFinder(flat))

print(rateFinder(initialbudget))
```

Comment: you need to set a higher recursion depth **sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)**

Comment: you're calling `rateFinder` in `rateFinder`. This can only happen up to a maximum depth (1000 in default CPython). You must be surpassing that. Think about your logic, debug with `print` calls.

Comment: @houzayfarifai I don't think that's going to help, the logic doesn't look right to me. For example, the `while` loop only ever runs one iteration.

Comment: I've never found a case where `sys.setrecursionlimit()` was actually needed.

Comment: Your loop will only break if `flat` happens to be exactly the right value for `(balance-flat)*(1+annualInterestRate/12.0)` to be 0. Do you have reason to believe that this is guaranteed to be the case eventually? Since `balance` doesn't start as a multiple of 10, in this case that will actually never happen.

Comment: I also don't follow the logic. Formula() never returns 'high', so the while loop goes on forever unless as @Kirill says the balance exactly equals 0.

Comment: I should have specified: one of the parameters of the problem dictates that the flat rate will be a multiple of 10.

Comment: In this case the flat rate should be 310

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
annualInterestRate=0.2  
balance=320000

ib=balance
air=annualInterestRate
flat=-10

while balance !=0:
    flat+=10
    month=1
    balance=ib
    while month<=12:
        balance=(balance-flat)*(1+air/12.0)
        month+=1
    if balance<0:
        print('Lowest Payment:',round(flat, 2))
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is the line `flat=0` in rateFinder. When formula() returns ('low'), it calls rateFinder with the updated value of flat, then sets flat back to 0. So ratefInder should look like this:

```
def rateFinder(initialbudget, flat):
    '''
    input starting balance
    return Flat rate needed to pay off balance in 12 months
    '''
    while formula(flat) != ('high'):
        if formula(flat)==('correct'):
            return('Lowest Payment:'+ ' ' + str(flat))
        else:
            flat+=10
            return(rateFinder(initialbudget, flat))
```

Having fixed that  and put `print flat, balance` after the for loop in formula(), you'll then find that the answer is between 300 and 310. So you need to refine your acceptance criteria.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I ended up recoding it anyways and it worked out.  Here was my solution, if you are curious